# How to access controls inside an asp.net wizard headertemplate?

Tags: asp.net, controls, wizard

This code to workaround having a wizard step title when wizard property `DisplaySideBar` is `False`, will not work, the label `lbl` will be `null`:

```
protected void Wizard1_ActiveStepChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Grab a reference to the label control
Label lbl = (Label)Wizard1.FindControl("lblStepTitle");
lbl.Text = Wizard1.ActiveStep.Title;
}
```

The HTML (ommited the wizard steps):

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="0" DisplaySideBar="False"
OnActiveStepChanged="Wizard1_ActiveStepChanged"
            OnNextButtonClick="Wizard1_NextButtonClick" 
            OnFinishButtonClick="Wizard1_FinishButtonClick">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="True" />
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Edit User Wizard
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblStepTitle" runat="server" Text="Step Title"></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
</asp:Wizard>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [blog](http://www.willstrohl.com/Blog/PostId/461/Wizard-Control-Programmatically-Access-the-Header), the solution is to first find a control created at runtime `HeaderContainer` no where documented by the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.headertemplate.aspx)

```
protected void Wizard1_ActiveStepChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Grab a reference to the label control
    Label lbl = (Label)Wizard1.FindControl("HeaderContainer").FindControl("lblStepTitle");
    lbl.Text = Wizard1.ActiveStep.Title;
}
```

Comment: What if there is no HeaderTemplate (or any other template) defined?