# Get an object (FileUpload) from a CompleteWizardStep

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, createuserwizard

I'm having difficulty trying to access an `FileUpload` on a event `ButtonImagem_Click` in the code behind in C# that is within a `CompleteWizardStep` on a `CreateUserWizard`.

Where is my code:

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Criar conta">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <%--...--%>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
        <asp:CompleteWizardStep runat="server" ID="CompleteWizardStep1">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /><br />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" ErrorMessage=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" ErrorMessage="Apenas são aceites imagens." ValidationExpression="(.*\.([Gg][Ii][Ff])|.*\.([Jj][Pp][Gg])|.*\.([Bb][Mm][Pp])|.*\.([pP][nN][gG])|.*\.([tT][iI][iI][fF])$)"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <br /><asp:Button ID="ButtonImagem" runat="server" Text="Concluir" OnClick="ButtonImagem_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Comment: Could you please add the code showing how you are trying to access the FileUpload control? Maybe the solution suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892141/how-to-access-controls-inside-an-asp-net-wizard-headertemplate) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, just needed to add `ContentTemplateContainer` like this:

```
FileUpload FileU = (FileUpload)CompleteWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("FileUpload1");
```